# Bootstrap : block image resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a YouTube picture below one for example :

[image]

and Bootstrap to display it:

```
<img src="{{img}}" alt="{{title}}" class="img-circle" width="60px" height="60px">
```

But the picture is crushed:

[image]

Am I missing a bootstrap property ? or a common hack ? Thanks !

**Edit :**

I finally found a trick to do the job :

```
<div class="crop">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EONhJ9qvCPY/default.jpg" alt="#" >
</div>
```

And

```
.crop{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    overflow:hidden;   
    position:relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.crop img {
    position: absolute;
    left: -27px;
    top: -18px;
}
```

Comment: Check the CSS. There is a css rule that is forcing the image to maintain it's ratio.

Comment: The image linked isn't a square, but you're giving it square dimensions.  It's gonna squish.  You could crop the image with `clip`.  If i'm not mistaken, the twitter class just gives a `border-radius`.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it on Plunker and its work fine. check the bootstrap link

Comment: Actually that's not a Bootstrap's bug. The image has black stripes on the sides, like a video vertically recorded, or it's more vertical than horizontal, then you need to crop it like @MatthewJohnson has commented. `img-circle` class just adds a 50% radius on the element. Did you tried with your example image (https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EONhJ9qvCPY/mqdefault.jpg)?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by picture is crushed? You're against the picture being in a circle, or the way it displays in the circle?

I think first of all it's crucial to understand, bootstrap as in whole is a framework containing rules for html, css & javascript. So to answer your question, there is no property/hack orso you're missing.

The reason why it displays like it displays, is because the image does not properly fit into the 60x60 image (or rather the crop of it in the circle) therefore, it crops out the parts that do not fit.

What I'm saying is, although it may not visually look like it, it still takes the 60x60 block and just puts a circle inside it and renders the outskirts transparent. There is virtually no way to avoid this, other than resizing the original picture.

So either

a) Edit the original picture in mspaint/photoshop/gimp whatever so it will fit better inside the circle crop
b) Go inside the bootstrap CSS properties and change the width and height properties of the img. Alternatively set a max-width and max-height for the images so it will not be stuck inside the 60x60 definition.

```
img {
  width: value;
  height: value;
}
```

The reason why you'd want to do it like that, is because in case you will want to use such an image in future, you will not have to specify the width and height properties through HTML code (which is causing you unnecessary displaying issues and code-readability problems to begin with), but it will automatically apply it to every element using the CSS rules.

Comment: What I was trying to say by "bootstrap property" was something to crop the image, a property that would transform a rectangle into a square, in order to have a proper ratio (because I need my picture to be 60*60px)

Comment: I'd strongly recommend doing this manually in some graphical editor (my personal recommendation would be photoshop, but any other will do just fine).